# Stuck with complex MySQL query syntax (joining a table with itself?)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have some language data in a MySQL table containing about 3.8 million rows (with indexes on virtually all fields):

```
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
| theWord | lcTheWord | spelling | thePOS | theUSAS        | register | period | variety | theDate |
+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
| to      | to        | l        | TO     | Z5             | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| direct  | direct    | l        | VVI    | M6             | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| others  | others    | l        | NN2    | A6.1-/Z8       | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| .       | .         | o        | .      | PUNC           | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| Both    | both      | u        | DB2    | N5             | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| his     | his       | l        | APPGE  | Z8m            | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| eyes    | eyes      | l        | NN2    | B1             | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| are     | are       | l        | VBR    | A3+            | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| never   | never     | l        | RR     | T1/Z6          | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
| at      | at        | l        | RR21   | N3.8+[i281.2.1 | p        |      1 | b       |    1608 |
```

So the same word can (and often will) be contained in the table multiple times, some with "l" for lowercase and some with "u" for uppercase.

I would now like to compare capitalisation of individual words across time-periods (e.g. 1 vs. 8), variety ("b" = British English, "a" = American English) etc. by creating output that is ranked by the proportion of upper to lowercase spelling. I will at some stage also want to restrict the data to certain parts-of-speech tags (thePOS) or semantic tags (theUSAS).

Unfortunately, my knowledge in SQL is very limited - and although I've tried quite a few things (e.g. joining the table with itself and trying to work out things from there), I have so far failed miserably.

Just to give you an example of the kind of things I have been trying:

```
SELECT l.theWord, count(l.theWord) as freq_low, count(u.theWord) as freq_up
FROM table_name l
INNER JOIN table_name u ON l.lcTheWord = u.lcTheWord
group by l.lcTheWord;
```

This is clearly the wrong approach, as it doesn't seem to use the necessary indexes (and takes too long for me to even see what it does...)

I realise this is a far less specific question than the guidelines suggest. Apologies! However, I'm wondering whether some kind soul could give me some pointers so that I can go on from there...?

Many thanks in advance!
Sebastian

Comment: Hm why you join? you need group by and having. like SELECT yourfields FROM yourtable GROUP BY lcTheWord HAVING COUNT(lcTheWord) > 1 This way you will get all the words that having more than one row and analyse them

Comment: Note that "adding an index to every column" isn't particular useful in general. The way the query optimiser works is that it picks a __single__ "most appropriate" index based on the query. Instead you want to add indexes that cover a number of columns based on your query, as adding indexes blindly takes extra disk space and makes inserts and updates slower. These blog posts gives a reasonable explanation of the indexes to use: http://learnmysql.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/mysql-optimizer-index-strategy.html http://craigballinger.com/blog/2010/10/useful-mysql-indexing-strategies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that you need a self join here - a `GROUP BY` should be sufficient. You can count words with `'u'`s and `'l'`s in the `spelling` column like this:

```
SELECT
    lcTheWord
,   SUM(CASE spelling WHEN 'u' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UpperCount
,   SUM(CASE spelling WHEN 'l' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LowerCount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY lcTheWord
```

Comment: Thanks - very helpful! I've now managed to execute a query that gives me the top 100 verbs in period 2 with a lowercase frequency of at least 5 ordered by proportion of UpperCount / LowerCount. Am I right in assuming that if I now wanted to compare such a list with the same restrictions for period 8, and order it by the greatest difference in proportions, I *would* need a join?

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Yes, you are correct - to compare the two lists you would need to join the results of two queries, not two tables. The query for the comparison becomes really complex - you would see a select from select, which would be hard to read and slow to execute. You may consider writing the results of your two queries into two tables indexed on `lcTheWord`, and then joining the pre-computed results.

Comment: OK - thanks for confirming! The problem is that I will have to pass on the query to a student who doesn't have access rights to create new tables, hoping he'll be able to modify the SQL in order to retrieve what he need - and there are too many options to pre-create them all for him. But I'll see what I can do. Thanks again!